# Error on nagios starting

Tags: nagios

I had nagios running on centOS. when i restart the nagios with

> /etc/init.d/nagios restart

it not showing any error. But when i check the status with

> /etc/init.d/nagios status

it showing *nagios not running*.

I run nagios with the help of

> /usr/local/nagios/bin/nagios /usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg

i getting following error

> Nagios 3.3.1 starting... (PID=12179)
>
> Local time is Tue Jul 16 10:08:17 CEST 2013
>
> Error: my_fcopy() failed to write to '/usr/local/nagios/var/spool/checkresults/nebmod2CKuKY': No space left on device
>
> Error: my_fcopy() failed to write to
> '/usr/local/nagios/var/spool/checkresults/nebmodMmhs0U': No space left on device

In the webconsole home page working properly.But when i click service or host i getting following error

> There doesn't appear to be any service status information in the status log...
>
> Make sure that Nagios is running and that you have specified the location of you status log correctly in the configuration files.

What would be the error?

**EDIT**

```
output of *df -h* 

Filesystem                  Size   Used   Avail  Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root 5.5G  5.3G     0    100%  /
tmpfs                       939M     0     939M   0%   /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                   485M   37M     423M   8%   /boot
```

Comment: That "No space left on device" error is suspect... Did you check the free space?

Comment: Please post the output of `df -h`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have any more room on your disc (see the 100% on that `df` output for `/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root`), so all sorts of things will start to break, including this.

Free up some space.

Specifically in this case, `nagios` tries to write to some (temp?) file, but can't

> Error: my_fcopy() failed to write to '/usr/local/nagios/var/spool/checkresults/nebmod2CKuKY': No space left on device

You could, if you would have another device, change the setting for the checkresults path with (see http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html for the setting) but then other things (like logging and who knows what) will fail because of no space.

Other services will also be affected by the way, so it is important to clean up some.

Comment: You are right. But still I can able to create new file in my PC and able write data on that file. Why nagios not able to copy files

Comment: Some filesystems reserve some space for special usage by e.g. root. (that's probably why you see 0 available, while you use 5.3 out of 5.5 G) The fact of the matter is that **your disk is full** according to both the error AND your `df` output. That means, your disk is full and the way to fix it would be to clean up some disk space.

Comment: you could remove reserved space by tune2fs -m 0 /dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root. Did you install nagios from source?

Comment: I would advice against setting minfree to 0, it's there for a reason :)

Answer (score 1):

From the comment of @SvW and answer of @Nanne

Nagios server make the log in /var/log/messages file in PC. This take more disk space, after i clear the all the data from /var/log/messages file.

Out put of *df -h*

```
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root   5.5G  4.2G  1.1G  81% /
tmpfs                          939M     0  939M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                      485M   37M  423M   8% /boot
```

After i disabled nagios log in configuration file (/usr/local/nagios/etc/nagios.cfg)

Then i restart nagios, it working fine.

Thanks.